# Flutter: Using Expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that returns a list of Widget like this:

```dart
buildCaption() {
  List<String> splittedCaption = caption.split(' ');
  List<Widget> mergedCaption = new List<Widget>();
  for (String captionSplit in splittedCaption) {
    print(captionSplit);
    if (captionSplit.contains('#')) {
      mergedCaption.add(Text(
        '$captionSplit ',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)
      ));
    } else {
      mergedCaption.add(Text('$captionSplit '));
    }
  }
  return mergedCaption;
}
```

Then, I have a Row Widget that looks like this:

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(child: Row(children: buildCaption())
  ]
)
```

However, the `Expanded` doesn't prevent the row from overflowing the screen size. Please how do I display the List of Widgets returned from the `buildCaption` method while still preventing it from overflowing the screen size?

Whole code:

```dart
buildPostFooter() {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      mediaUrl.length > 1 ? Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          mediaUrl,
          (index, media) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: currentMedia == index
                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
              )
            );
          }
        )
      ) : Text(''),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 15.0)),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: handleLikePost,
            child: Icon(
              isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              size: 28.0,
              color: Colors.pink
            )
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0)),
          Text(
            '$likeCount likes',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            )
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => showComments(
              context,
              postId: postId,
              ownerId: ownerId,
              mediaUrl: mediaUrl
            ),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.chat,
              size: 28.0,
              color: Colors.blue[900]
            )
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0)),
          Text(
            '$commentCount comments',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: mediaUrl.length > 0 && caption.isNotEmpty ? 10.0 : 0.0
        )
      ),
      mediaUrl.length > 0 && caption.isNotEmpty ? Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
            child: Text(
              '$username ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              )
            )
          ),
          Expanded(child: Row(children: buildCaption()))
        ],
      ) : timeWidget(),
      mediaUrl.length > 0 && caption.isNotEmpty ? timeWidget() : Text('')
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to wrap each child text in an Expanded. Don't wrap the Row in an Expanded.

Comment: @Smashing That throws an error: ```Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.```

Comment: Wrapping second Row in Expanded is necessary because it tells the second Row how big it should be drawn because it is inside a Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: caption.split(' ').map(
                    (item) {
                      if (item.contains('#')) {
                        return TextSpan(
                          text: '$item ',
                          recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                            ..onTap = () => print('hashtag$item'),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        );
                      } else if (item.contains('.')) {
                        return TextSpan(
                          text: '$item ',
                          recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                            ..onTap = () => print('https://www.$item'),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return TextSpan(
                          text: '$item ',
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]
        )
```

Comment: That didn't work either. It removed the overflow error but it made the text look weird

Comment: It happened because all the Text Widgets are constrained by the second Row width.

Comment: I removed the second row, used only one row (wrapped in expanded), with each child text wrapped in expanded and the text still looks weird. Here is an image so you can see for yourself: https://imgur.com/a/VgtJ8US how to fix that?

Comment: Can you look at the whole code i just added to the question to see how the structure looks like, if I remove the second row, how do I call ```buildCaption()```?

Comment: First off, what do you want to achieve because you only asked how to prevent overflowing screen size. After looking at the image, I think your approach is wrong using "List" of Text Widget

Comment: Oh, what i am trying to do is format a caption. So for example, if a caption has a word that is prefixed with '#' then that word gets a different style from other words, same with links, when a word has a dot in between it, it gets a different style from other words. I didn't know how to do this so creating a "List" of Text Widget is the only approach that i've tried and it work, only problem now is with rendering it to the screen. If you know any other approach that works better, please let me know

Comment: Thank you. Although, i have another challenge with this same ```Expanded``` widget. It's in a different context, but im still getting the same screen overflow error, i don't want to ask a new question, so is it possible for us to chat on SO chat or something?

Comment: I think it's better for you to make a new post because first, I can't possibly check post all the time and second, maybe the problem is beyond my understanding and I can't really help you. By making a new post, wider portion of people could help you

Answer (score 1):

you can`t use row for multiple text widget and expect line breaks

you should use Rich Text for multiple style in one text

try below code:

```
  buildCaption() {
    List<String> splittedCaption = caption.split(' ');
    List<TextSpan> mergedCaption = List<TextSpan>();
    for (String captionSplit in splittedCaption) {
      print(captionSplit);
      if (captionSplit.contains('#')) {
        mergedCaption.add(TextSpan(
            text: '$captionSplit ',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)
        ));
      } else {
        mergedCaption.add(TextSpan(text: '$captionSplit '));
      }
    }
    return mergedCaption;
  }
```

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: RichText(
      text: new TextSpan(
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        children: buildCaption(),
      ),
    ))
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `SingleChildScrollView`  instead of  `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do, but here you have a horizontal scrollable list. If you want to use row I will suggest using the **Wrap**. widget.

```
final List<Widget> widgetList = buildCaption();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: widgetList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return index;
                  }
               );
    }
```

2. suggestion: Regarding the overflow you can use a Container instead of Expanded, and set `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5` on the Container, this is eqvivalent to 50% of screen width.
3. suggestion: You can use Grid-list and set crossAxisCount: widgetList().length if you want everything to be in one line, se example here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Comment: Please look at the full code i posted. Basically, I have a list of text widgets inside a row but they are overflowing the screen, and i am trying to get them to have an automatic line break instead of overflowing the screen